# iMac 3GHz w NVIDIA 9400 -- Unable to install generic nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, imac

I can't install the latest NVIDIA drivers for the 9400 on this iMac (Early 2010 Model, 20.5" Screen).

I'm running Windows 7 64bit, and I tried installing both the 9400M and 9400 drivers.  The actual NVIDIA lookup utility on the site says it's a 9400, but the apple documentation says its an M model.. Regardless, neither one will find the hardware.

I'm just trying to run CIV5, but it's performing absolutely horrible.  It ran pretty terrible with the stock Windows 7 64bit drivers on another PC I have, so I know I definitely need better drivers for this machine to run it smoother.  Anyone ever deal with this sort of thing before?  I've used tens of NVIDIA cards before and never had a problem like this.

Oh, and Apple has no driver updates from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the nVidia chips in the iMac are the Mobile variants. Grab [the drivers](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/27358-v26063-windows-7vista-64bit-nvidia-desktop-and-oem-mobile/) from Laptop Video 2 Go and install 'em